# 2 out of 4 CPU cores are running 10C hotter under full load

Tags: laptop, cpu, intel-core-i5

My laptop is an Acer Helios 300 with i5-8300h, GTX 1060, and 16GB RAM. I have noticed that core 1 and core 3 run 10-15C hotter under multi CPU load.

**Throttlestop benchmark temps**

[image: Throttlestop benchmark temps]

I have repasted the heatsink with arctic silver 5 multiple times by trying different methods like the dot, X, and spreading it out. Every time the delta between cores is present. There are no deformations on the heatsink that I could notice.

I'm unable to understand the reason for this. Can someone please help me in identifying the cause for this?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. You're nowhere near prochot. I have a machine where one entire CPU runs at 10-15° hotter than the other. It's in the design, the airflow from one passes the other so it gets less cooling. It's been like that since new… 10 years ago. No issues.

Comment: Understood. Thanks :)